# PHP : YYYY-MM-DD vs. strtotime

Tags: php, mysql, date, strtotime

I want some insights on inserting data into MySQL for later comparison. I know that those format `date(Y-m-d)` and `strtotime(date(Y-m-d))` have its own specific kinda usage. But I'm new to the field of MySQL and PHP. So I need a list of pros and cons of use among you guys. Which one are you using and please give me a little why.

**Which is more efficient and correct to use `date(Y-m-d)` or `strtotime(date(Y-m-d))`?**

I want to know if it gets any advantage in comparing time between these queries:

```
 1. `select * from table where '2012-11-01' between date1 and date2`
 2. `select * from table where '1351702800' between date1 and date2`
```

Could you please point me out which one is faster when it's dealing with a large MySQL dataset?

Comment: They produce *completely different* results: one produces a string formatted as `Y-m-d`, the other converts that string back to a timestamp again (so is rather pointless).

Comment: Since you're asking, I prefer using [the `DateTime` class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) -- it's got much better functionality than the old `date()` funtion and its friends.

Comment: @eggyal There're some reasons behind this question. One of them is when I comparing the time in mySQL for example: 

Should I use this :


`select * from table where '2012-11-01' between date1 and date2` 
or this:
`select * from table where '1351702800' between date1 and date2`

Comment: @SDC Could you please give me some example on that class. Or an exact link to the source would be appreciated.

Comment: @Wilf - it's built into PHP. My original comment included a link to the manual page, which has plenty of good examples.

Comment: You should store temporal values using [MySQL's temporal data types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-types.html), so that MySQL correctly understands the meaning of the data and how to manipulate it.  MySQL supports a number of different [literal formats for temporal data](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-literals.html), but none of them involve the underlying UNIX timestamp: so the short answer to your question is to use [`date('Y-m-d')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) (or better yet, the `DateTime` class as suggested by @SDC).

Comment: @Wilf: what type `date1` and `date2`? It might be `date` or `integer`. So your choice is based on the data type, not on preferences.

Comment: That said, if you are stuck with a literal UNIX timestamp, you can use MySQL's [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) function to convert it (but in this case, that'd just be converting from *x* to *y* simply to convert back to *x* again, so as I said in my first comment, rather pointless).

Comment: For me date() is more comfortable to using in PHP code later, but SQL with timestamp can be little bit faster executed by SQL server.
If I need just date without time precision i use date().

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion Date types are better to use. The ms you need to convert a Timestamp back to a readable format will lose against the time that the SQL query does take longer to read the entirely Date from the database.

**Timestamp is more optimized**, however you need PHP to convert - **slower**.

**Date type is already in readable format**, no need to convert - **faster**.

**Edit:** And MySQL have great functions to deal with Date types!